# Display permanently current time in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have three questions, all of them closely related to each other. The most important one is the first one.

First: I am trying to display the current time in the format hours:minutes:seconds, so

```
set systemTime [clock seconds]

puts "The time is: [clock format $systemTime -format %H:%M:%S]"
```

But the above clock should be permanently updated, that is, the seconds-part of the clock should be running all the time.

Second: In the next step I would like to display milliseconds and they should be updated as well.

Third: I would like to execute a procedure at a certain point of time. More precisely: At a certain time, say 16:20 (the format here is hours:minutes), tcl musst execute a procedure, say proc SumUpInt, which I defined. It may be possible that I want to consider seconds and milliseconds as well when executing the proc.

I do not know how to do this. I have found many similar questions on some web sites, also on stack overflow, but I was not able to adapt some of these solutions to my problem.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I am trying to display the current time" -- where? In a GUI, in your terminal? What's your user interface?

Comment: "display milliseconds and they should be updated as well" -- updated how often? Every second, tenth of a second, millisecond?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more accurate at these points. So, first of all I would like to display the clock in my terminal. Milliseconds must be updated every millisecond.

Comment: where in your terminal? While it's displaying the time (somewhere), you're able to still interact normally, entering commands and so on? You need to be very clear about your scenario

Comment: Exactly. I am still able to interact.

Comment: Have you thought about what you're asking? A fast gaming monitor can only show information at 144Hz, one update around every 7 ms. Even worse, the human eye can only handle about 30Hz. So it's useless to update more frequently than about every 25ms. And even then, the last two digits will just be a blur.

Comment: And _where_ in the terminal is this clock supposed to display? In your prompt? In one corner? Is this in a terminal in a GUI desktop or in a console? Why Tcl? I'm just about done prompting you for information.

Comment: It is in a console.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an output directive in `clock format` for milliseconds, so perhaps:

```
proc timestamp {} {
    set t [clock milliseconds]
    set systemTime [expr {int($t / 1000)}]
    set milliSeconds [expr {$t % 1000}]
    return [format "%s.%03d" [clock format $systemTime -format %T] $milliSeconds]
}

timestamp      ;# => 14:41:13.032
```

---

You can turn this "realtime" with

```
proc run_timestamp {} {
    puts -nonewline "\r[timestamp] "
    flush stdout
    after 100 run_timestamp
}
run_timestamp
vwait forever
```

But the `vwait` means this will block the Tcl interpreter. I don't have any thoughts right now about how to integrate this into your terminal.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works! It displays the time in the desired format. But once I have executed your code, the clock does not run. It still shows the same time without updating it. Milliseconds should be updated permanently (every millisecond). If you use the time format hours:minutes:seconds then seconds should be updated every second. So, at every point of time the clock should display the correct time.

Comment: For me, `run_timestamp` works as expected.

Comment: Many thanks!!! It works! Now using 'clock scan' I can capture a certain point of time in a variable and continue my work with it. Thanks again! Your code was extremely helpful!!